# PHP Magic Method __unset() does not work on calling unset function

Tags: php, magic-methods, unset

I could not understand why `__unset()` not work.

```
class myclass {
    public $name = array();

    public function __set($arraykey, $value){
        $this->name[$arraykey] = $value;
    }

    public function __isset($argu){
        return isset($this->name[$argu]);
    }

    public function __unset($argu){ 
        echo "Working: Unset $this->name[$argu]";
        unset($this->name[$argu]);
    }
}

$obj = new myclass;
$obj->name = 'Arfan Haider';

var_dump(isset($obj->name));

unset($obj->name);
```

I read that whenever the `unset()` function is called, then Magic Method `__unset()` automatically is called and unsets the variable.

In above code I am using unset but it does not call `__unset()`. Why? Am I missing something in understanding the Magic Method `__unset()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magic methods `__set`, `__get`, `__isset` and `__unset` only get called when accessing *inaccessible* properties. That means either private properties, protected properties (accessed outside of a child class) or properties which haven't been created.

Calling your internal variable `$_name` instead of `$name`, or setting `$name` to `private` or `protected` instead of `public` will fix your problem.

**Note**:

You should only use `protected` properties or functions when they need to be accessible from an extending class - don't use it just because.

Answer (score 4):

> __unset() is invoked when unset() is used on *inaccessible* properties. [(source)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.unset)

Thus it can only be effective on inaccessible (i.e. `private` and `protected`) props.